# How can I get the variable that a python file with a path prints when I call that python file from a shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, variables, piping

For some reason when I run this in my shell script only $exec_file and $_dir get passed into module_test.py, but neither $filename nor $modified_file get passed.

```
mod_test=$( /path/module_test.py $modified_file $_dir $filename )
```

(path is just a normal path that I decided to shorten for the sake of this example)
Am I typing this wrong? I am trying to get the output (an integer) of my module_test.py to be put into the variable mod_test.

My variables are:

```
modified_file = _File
_dir = /path to directory/
file = _File.py
```

Comment: Post an example with the real values of the variables.

Comment: How are you receiving the arguments inside the python script?

Comment: @ronakg I just try to print the array of sys.argv which shows two elements missing.

Comment: you should do `set -x` before running the python script in your bash script. That way you would know if correct command is getting executed or not. What if `$filename` is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, you need to surround `$_dir` with quotes because it contains spaces, i.e.:

```
mod_test=$( /path/module_test.py $modified_file '$_dir' $filename )
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro, turns out that it was because I had a silly typo and when fixing it everything works. I marked your question as the correct answer because you helped me.